# Ransack returning filtered excel or executing filtered delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ransack

I am using ransack to filter a list of products. I now would like to reuse the current selection to return an excel file instead (so I can put a link in the same page "download filtered products as excel") or perform a delete on the filtered results. E.g. the called URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bstatusowner_id_or_client_producer_id_eq%5D=&q%5Bkind_eq%5D=&q%5Bstatus_eq%5D=9&commit=Select
```

The easiest way I see to return an excel is to pass the **same** parameters is to pass the same URL with the only addition a .xls at the end of products:

```
http://localhost:3000/products.xls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bstatusowner_id_or_client_producer_id_eq%5D=&q%5Bkind_eq%5D=&q%5Bstatus_eq%5D=9&commit=Select
```

How to I reuse the current URL in the view to create the new URL?

Then regarding the mass delete: I have no idea how to handle that, as I have only used RESTful routes to date. Say I follow the above idea and reuse the URL again but send it to a (yet to be defined??) mass delete action. How should I route that as RESTful as possible? Just adding method: :delete? And where in my controller would I route that?

Bit at a loss.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key point is that reuses the ransack search form and parameters, not the url.

If you just want to use index action to execute delete or render excel, you can keep route.rb unchanged.

In view, I assume you have a ransack form

```
<%= search_form_for @products do |f| %>
   # YOUR CONDITIONS
   <%= f.submit 'query' %>  #Just query

   # add two new buttons.
   <button id="output_xls" name="output_xls">Output</button>
   <button id="mass_delete" name="mass_delete">Delete</button>
<% end %>
```

You can use javascript on 2 buttons. When button is clicked, JS adds corresponding parameters to the form and submits it.

```
$('#output_xls').click(function(){
  $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="format" value="xls" />');
  $('form').get(0).submit();
});

$('#mass_delete').click(function(){
  $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="method" value="delete" />');
  $('form').get(0).submit();
});
```

In controller, you can decide logic depending on parameters.

```
def index

  #EXECUTE RANSACK SEARCH

  if params.delete(:method) == 'delete'
    #DELETE RECORDS
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {# DO YOUR REDIRECTING }
    format.xls {# OUTPUT YOUR EXCEL }
  end 
end
```

Remember to register the mime type in config/initializers/mime_types.rb.

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.ms-excel", :xls
```

I wrote a lot, if you have any questions, please comment below :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have the feeling that the javascript is not necessary. There is something on that in http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form. I will try to combine both and post any results here.

Comment: @Kostas Georgokitsos Did you get it working without the javascript?

Comment: I used a completely different approach